# multiple commands in the same session with ssh

Tags: session, ssh, command, execution

I am currently using the Trilead ssh2 library and when i try to execute multiple commands (using execCommand) in the same session, I get "a remote execution has already started" error.

Just wanted clarify, the session is limited to one system command; does that mean I can only send one command through execCommand() per connection?  Is there any other alternative besides injecting multiple commands with semicolons?